# how do i get multiple twitter name using API querystring?

Tags: twitter

HI,how do i get multiple twitter name using API querystring,exmaple i need to populate related with the name of 'john'.how can i do that here i have one example below
'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3Ajohn' by this example we can see only particular user name only but i want related name.Kindly let me know ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OR operator...

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3ADWRoelands+OR+from%3AJohn