# how do you get multiple Twitter names using api querystring

Tags: twitter

HI,how do i get multiple twitter name using API querystring,exmaple i need to populate related with the name of 'john'.how can i do that here i have one example below 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3Ajohn' by this example we can see only particular user name only but i want related name.Kindly let me know ASAP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i get multiple twitter name using API querystring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563196/how-do-i-get-multiple-twitter-name-using-api-querystring)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OR operator...

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3ADWRoelands+OR+from%3AJohn